# Is it "OK" to use a low end NIC for a dedicated heart beat between two servers?

Tags: nic, heartbeat

I've got nice big server-grade NICs on my servers busy interfaces.  Soon I'll be setting up a cluster that will have a dedicated heat-beat.

Do I really need to use an expensive server grade NIC for this?  Or will a low-end desktop NIC suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it work? Yes.

Will the driver drag down the network performance of the whole server? Maybe. In my testing, quality server type NIC's (typically four porters) had a much lower kernel interrupt rate than the cheap consumer NICs.

You have to realize how miserable the drivers are for most chip-of-the-day cheap consumer NIC's. If you are fortunate, it won't drag down the whole system, or occasionally get in a loop and freeze up.

If you go this route, at least pick a discrete NIC with a good chip on it and good driver support, such as Intel.

Answer (score 3):

The quantity of traffic will be low. So no, it probably doesn't matter if they're not "Intel *Server* Adapters" capable of pushing wirespeed with ToE. They will need to be absolutely reliable to prevent false-positives though. So don't skimp on the chipset brand and associated drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Surely you'd have on-board NICs you'd use for this? I'm sure I've not seen a discrete NIC ina server for years.

I can understand using big discrete NICs for data as an upgrade

But yes, as long as they are reliable.

Comment: The onboard NIC is in use.

Comment: There is only one onboard NIC? Why not use this for the heartbeat,  and use server-grade ones to replace usage?

Comment: I've got a front-end and back-end LAN, both of which will have traffic.  The "Business End" will have a teamed dual port server NIC, the other will have the built in NIC.  I've read that one should keep a heartbeat on it's own dedicated segment, so need to add a NIC.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can get drivers for the OS, especially if you're running 64-bit.

I don't like cutting corners on front-line servers, personally, but I can't say for sure that the server-grade ones cause less problems than the lower end ones.

Answer (score 0):

Expensive or cheap, as long as it's reliable and has a driver for the server OS you're installing it in, should be fine.